How to bundle all necessary dependencies in pyinstaller .exe file?
I have a typing game that is made using django and websockets ,I want to make ".exe file" to run this game on another pc that does not even have python installed !!
I tried this code below and it worked only in my current working pc.
Here is a Runner.py code that i used in the pyinstaller cmd
import subprocess
import time

# Start the Django server
subprocess.Popen(["python", "manage.py", "runserver"], shell=True)

# Wait for the server to start
time.sleep(5)

# Open the webpage in Chrome
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  # Adjust if necessary
subprocess.Popen([chrome_path, "http://localhost:8000"])  # Adjust URL if necessary

in the target pc only chrome opens but the server doesnt run thus python manage.py runserver is not working maybe cause the target pc doesnt even have python nor django installed ? and it cant find the manage.py file?
so what im thinking is i need a way to bundle everything in a way that it workes on any device.
Note : the pyinstaller cmd is pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole runner.py

why in the love of LINUS TORVALDS you would want to do such a horrible malicious thing? this abomination of an application? xD  Now let's be serious. You are compiling not the whole django app. You are compiling a file, that runs a command. That's all.

@ZwickVitaly i wanted only to have this web app to be bundled in a way that if i sent exe file to a target pc , it will be able to run it without the need of django or even python

well then you will have to dig deep into hidden dependencies of django
